# What happens if App fabric publishing cache service stops in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, service, distributedcache

What happens if "App fabric publishing cache service" stops in SharePoint 2013.When I try to browse web app getting run time error.I have 2 servers in farm, do I need to start the service in both of the servers?

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix the App Fabric Service (Distributed Cache Servie). A lot of things depend upon on this service. i.e.

- Newsfeeds
- Authentication
- OneNote client access
- Security Trimming
- Page load performance

If the cache Cluster is down then you will see Runtime error, unexpected error, access denied, no newsfeed, page loading slowly and so on.

It can be on one server, Follow this guide to repair the DC: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396